# Do I need to register a domain name for my subdomain?

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain

I want to know if I need to register a separate domain name for my subdomain (example.mydomain.com). 
Do I need to register another domain name to feed my subdomain?

Comment: Of course.. you still need the SLD (the main `example.com`).

Comment: @cybermonkey. Does that mean I will have to register a separate domain for every subdomain I create. Meaning that for me to have example.mydomain.com, I must have registered two domain names (mydomain.com and example.com)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming problem. It might be more suited to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: No, you do not need to register a separate domain name for your subdomain.

Depending on your domain name provider, there will be options to create additional subdomains.